# How to goto back page on click of cancel button in ZUL apge

Tags: zk

I wanted to navigate to the browsers back page (History) onclick of Back button. How I can achieve this usign zul page? I have one option of keeping the hidden field and redirect via composer or using zk's if condition. But any other solution like javascripts function are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [client side javascript](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2010/April/Client_Side_Programming#Listen_to_DOM_event) in combination with Java Script's [history object](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_history.asp):

```
<zk xmlns="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul">
    <div>
         <button label='back' 
                 xmlns:w="client" 
                 w:onClick="history.back();" 
         />                
    </div>
</zk>
```